# New Line Characters Causing Inconsistent Behavior in ASP.NET RegularExpressionValidator

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I am using a `RegularExpressionValidator` to limit the amount of text entered in a `TextArea`. The expression is `"^[\s\S]{0,750}$"`. This almost works perfectly, but I've noticed some strange behavior.

If I input 749 characters and one newline (or 748 characters and two newlines, etc) I am seeing some seemingly incorrect and inconsistent behavior between browsers. I am guessing this has something to do with the newline being treated inconsistently as 1 character or 2 (CR & LF).

IE 8 - Client side validation fails because this is (correctly) seen as 751 characters and the page cannot be submitted.
IE 9 & Firefox - Client side validation passes and the value is posted. However, on postback the validation error message is shown. The value is still accepted, though, which is wrong because I end up with 751 characters.

Does anybody know what is causing this and how I can actually limit my text area to N characters?

Edit: Corrected regex

Edit: Just following up on this. It was difficult to determine how exactly the RegularExpressionValidator was working so I just switched it to a custom validator and did the regex check manually. This solved the issue.

Comment: This regex does not make sense unless characters alternate between spaces and nonspaces, and vary between zero and 1500, with only an even number allowed. Perhaps you mean `^(\s|\S){0,750}$`, in which case all characters are matched. This can also be accomplished with `^.{0,750}$` and a multiline modifier.

Comment: Is your regex supposed to be `^[\s\S]{0,750}$` (between 0 and 750 of any character including line breaks)?  What you currently have means alternate one whitespace character and one non-whitespace character between 0 and 750 times (up to 1500 total characters).

Comment: Sorry about that. Yeah, I meant ^[\s\S]{0,750}$. That's how it is in the code, I just zoned out while typing the question.

Comment: One thing that might be affecting your results: `$` in many engines does not mean 'end of string' but 'end of string optionally preceded by a newline' (`\z` matches only end of string). The codebehind (.NET) uses this interpretation, but JavaScript has `$` as end-of-string only. I'm not sure if the translation of the validator to client side validation takes this into account...

Comment: Of course, `$` could be misimplemented in the browser as well.